# webpack css-loader background-image error loading

Tags: angular, webpack, babeljs, css-loader, babel-register

I'm working on an Angular2+ES2015+Babel+Webpack project and I bumped into this problem when including images on CSS files and using `css-loader`, it's already been hours hunting the problem but no luck so far:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/home/home.component.css
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /path/to/project/src/app/home/images/penguin.png: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
> 1 | �PNG
    | ^
  2 | 
  3 | 
  4 | IHDR��>a�gAMA��7��!�IDATx��]xTEמ�B�"�)"��� ��T?@?�iRiD�tPA��)"���$��K���K���wτ���f��M6a���OHؽ3s�3gΜ93#���>���x��}����>���x�Ƅ&���f&�o>
                                                ��ɉI�O����#S�a-a
                                                                  �9�8!�W1<�)O�G�j��B�
    at Parser.pp.raise (/path/to/project/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:22:13)
    at Parser.getTokenFromCode (/path/to/project/node_modules/babylon/lib/tokenizer/index.js:561:12)
    at Parser.readToken (/path/to/project/node_modules/babylon/lib/tokenizer/index.js:180:21)
    at Parser.readToken (/path/to/project/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/flow.js:164:22)
    at Parser.nextToken (/path/to/project/node_modules/babylon/lib/tokenizer/index.js:169:21)
    at Parser.parse (/path/to/project/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/index.js:128:12)
    at parse (/path/to/project/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:47:47)
    at File.parse (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:517:34)
    at File.parseCode (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:603:20)
    at /path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:49:12
    at File.wrap (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:563:16)
    at Pipeline.transform (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:47:17)
    at Object.transformFileSync (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/node.js:144:10)
    at compile (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:129:20)
    at loader (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/src/app/home/home.component.css:6:2430)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.loaderContext.exec (/path/to/project/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:88:7)
    at Object.module.exports (/path/to/project/node_modules/to-string-loader/src/to-string.js:6:54)
```

If you have a search for the error you'l find similar situations on github issues and stackoverflow, but not quite the same. In all of them the lack of an image loader is pointed out (png file here) but in my case I have one working perfectly. **If `require('../image/penguin.png')` directly on a JS file it just gets loaded and exported to output path!**

My process and Webpack configuration is quite complex, large and split into different files but here is the interesting part

```
import config from './config';

{
  [...]
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        loader: 'eslint'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        loader: 'postcss?pack=lint'
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.(spec|e2e)\.js$/],
        loaders: [
          'babel',
          'angular2-template'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        loaders: [
          'to-string',
          'css?-import',
          'postcss?pack=process'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        loaders: [
          'url?limit=10000&name=assets/images/[name].[ext]?[hash:20]',
          'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=6'
        ]
      },
      [...]
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: resolve(config.paths.dist),
    publicPath: `http://${config.dev.host}:${config.dev.port}/`,
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },
  [...]
}
```

And here the piece of css that triggers the error

```
[...]
.post-image {
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(./images/penguin.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If it looks strange to use `to-string-loader` for css it is because `angular2-template-loader` allows to inline CSS directly into Angular2 Componet's `stylesUrl`

Because of the error stack it seems like once css-loader has done the job the png file is not being loaded with the defined loader (url!image-webpack) but it is loaded with babel-register? So I `console.log` the result from css-loader, and there is the expected image `require`:

```
[...]
exports.push([module.id, ".post-image{height:150px;background-image:url(" + require("./images/penguin.png") + ");background-position:50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}", ""]);
```

So I made babel ignore png files

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "angular2",
    "stage-3"
  ],
  "ignore": ["*.png"]
}
```

And this throws a slightly different error because babel is ignoring images, but in the end seems to be the same:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/home/home.component.css
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at loader (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/src/app/home/home.component.css:6:2430)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.loaderContext.exec (/path/to/project/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:88:7)
    at Object.module.exports (/path/to/project/node_modules/to-string-loader/src/to-string.js:6:54)
```

I'm stuck with no a clue, I'm going WTF just setting an image background on a CSS file should be easy as pie

Any thoughts??

Comment: I am also facing the 'Slightly different errors' in my app. Using angular2 with webpack.

Answer (score 4):

Finally made it.

The source of the problem was at the end of the chain: `to-string-loader`

The loader uses `Loader.exec` to handle the response from `css-loader` but this code has a know [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/667)

Apart from stop using the loader some solutions can be found in that issue. But by far the best one is creating an adhoc loader as proposed by Mathias Raacke (@ooc) [in this other issue](https://github.com/gajus/to-string-loader/issues/2#issuecomment-221586058)

I hope this helps someone else not wasting this much time!

Comment: So what was your solution?  I'm confused

Comment: You can create your [custom loader](https://github.com/gajus/to-string-loader/issues/2#issuecomment-221586058) or use [another loader](https://github.com/smithad15/css-to-string-loader)

Comment: the solution in your link to use `css-to-string-loader` worked for me!   Thanks!